# which max column is true

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with 6 fields--- customer id and 5 indicator variables.

```
cid, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5
101, 1,  1,  1 , 0 , 0
102, 1,  1,  0 , 0 , 0
103, 1,  0,  0 , 0 , 0
```

I want to get for each cust id which max field has true indicator.

Output should be

```
for 101 -> f3;
for 102 -> f2;
for 103 -> f1;
```

**SQL code to reproduce the example**

```
CREATE TABLE customer_status
(
cid int,
f1 int,
f2 int,
f3 int,
f4 int,
f5 int);
insert into customer_status values(
101, 1,  1,  1 , 0 , 0);

insert into customer_status values(
102, 1,  1,  0 , 0 , 0);

insert into customer_status values(
103, 1,  0,  0 , 0 , 0);
```

Comment: is there a possibility, that all f's are 0 ? Or only f5 = 1 but all others are 0 ?

Comment: @Kadet, yes it is possible all f's are zero. 
No, f5 can not be 'one' singularly. all rows should have consecutive ones.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your `f` values are only ones, you can sum up all `f`s and transform the result into a string:

```
SELECT cid, 
       CONCAT('f', f1+f2+f3+f4+f5)
FROM customer_status
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jQ94SqPpLAt3pnMsKDnbr/1).

Comment: I was thinking this, but can the source data be 1 0 1 1 0 was my concern here.

Comment: This solution works efficiently with the given data and under the assumption all rows have consecutive ones. As this was marked as the accepted answer, it seems that the assumption is correct. @Nathan_Sav

Comment: So, this is question to @Vinnet, because this is only your assumption that if f5 =1 then all f1.. 4 must be 1. Maybe include your assumption in solution to make it complete ?

Comment: If this is a question for Vinnet, post it in the comments section of the OP's post. @Kadet

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option

```
select cid, 
  'f' || length(rtrim(f1 || f2 || f3 || f4 || f5, '0')) result
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Also, below is slightly refactored version that does not require explicit listing of columns, thus works for any number of F{N} columns

```
select cid, 'f' || length(rtrim(zzz, '0')) result
from your_table t, unnest([struct(
  translate(format('%t', (select as struct * except(cid) from unnest([t]))), '(), ', '') as zzz
)])
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer handle all cases including:

- when there is no 1 in any field
- if 1 is only in f5 field (but not in f4,f3,f2,f1) field

```sql
SELECT
  cid,
  CASE 
    WHEN f5 = 1 THEN 'f5'
    WHEN f4 = 1 THEN 'f4'
    WHEN f3 = 1 THEN 'f3'
    WHEN f2 = 1 THEN 'f2'
    WHEN f1 = 1 THEN 'f1'
    ELSE ' '
    END
    AS result
FROM customer_status
```